# unable to get a response with goqu

Tags: go

I am attempting to use https://github.com/doug-martin/goqu and although the query is correct and I am connected to the database the response is always empty.

```
func goquBuilder() goqu.DialectWrapper {
    return goqu.Dialect("postgres")
}

    func (r *CourseRepo) GetAll() ([]Course, error) {
    var courses []Course

    query, res, err := goquBuilder().From(
        goqu.S(schema).Table("courses")).Prepared(true).ToSQL()

    if err != nil {
        clogger.Error(err)
    }

    for r := range res {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }

    fmt.Println(query)

    return courses, nil
}
```

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are not executing the query to get the result set and maybe you need to use a database connection object to execute the query and get the result set, do you want more explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm junior in go but check this out please,

```
func goquBuilder() goqu.DialectWrapper {
    return goqu.Dialect("postgres")
}

func (r *CourseRepo) GetAll() ([]Course, error) {
    var courses []Course

    query := goquBuilder().From(
        goqu.T(schema, "courses")).Select(goqu.I("id"), goqu.I("name"), goqu.I("description"))

    sql, args, err := query.ToSQL()

    if err != nil {
        clogger.Error(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(sql, args...)
    if err != nil {
        clogger.Error(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var c Course
        err := rows.Scan(&c.ID, &c.Name, &c.Description)
        if err != nil {
            clogger.Error(err)
            return nil, err
        }
        courses = append(courses, c)
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        clogger.Error(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return courses, nil
}
```

Comment: I had to do some adjustments but you were correct.